# SQLite cursor stays null

Tags: android, sqlite

Iam trying to find an average of certain values in a column in my sQLite database. This column has some null and some not null values. I need to calculate the average of based on last 1, 5 or 10 not null values. But when i try to fetch data through my query i always get the cursor as null.
Kindly help.
heres my code for fetching the last not null value of mileage.

```
 public void calculateAvgMileage(Prediction predictMileage) 
 {

     if(predictMileage.isChkLastMileage1()==true)
       {
String [] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROW_ID, KEY_KM, KEY_FUEL_QTY, KEY_FUEL_PRICE, KEY_TOTAL_COST, KEY_MILEAGE, KEY_DATE,KEY_TANK_FULL};
            predictionCursor = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM fuel_table ORDER BY _id DESC LIMIT 1", null);

            if(predictionCursor!=null && predictionCursor.getColumnCount()>0)
            {
                predictionCursor.moveToLast();
                String predictionMileage= predictionCursor.getString(5);
                if(predictionMileage==null)
                {
                predictionCursor.moveToPrevious();
                }
                else
                {
                avgMileagePrediction.setpredictionMileage(Double.valueOf(predictionMileage));
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read the count of columns before you have forced the cursor to actually read the data with a call to `moveToFirst` or a similar function.

Comment: Well, I did the same thing in other functions and they worked. HOever here my issue is that the cursor is not getting the value from the query itself.The next steps are never reached.

Comment: You didn't understand what I wrote, did you? Insert a call to `moveToFirst` before the `getColumnCount` check.

Comment: Nope!!still not working. What I am trying to do here is get the last mileage from my database and find the fuel qty required to travel certain kms. As in by calulating fuelQty = km/mileage(obtained from the database) but I am getting "infinity" as the result for fuel qty.

Comment: Is that mileage a string or a number?